# Displaying Indian Number system (Lakhs and Crores) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want a custom formula for Google Sheets to format both crores and lakhs in Indian Number System. I have the custom formula for positive, but couldn't figure out how to add negative number system in that.

Custom Formula for positive numbers: `[>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0;[>99999]##\,##\,##0;##,##0`

Lakhs: `1,000,000` -> `10,00,000`

Crores: `100,000,000` -> `10,00,00,000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional number formats are limited to two conditions plus a default when neither condition is satisfied. The conditions are limited to a comparison operator and a value.

To use an Indian number format, you need two conditions to handle lakhs and crores, so there is no condition left to use to test for negative/positive.

The easiest workaround is to use a `text()` formula like as shown by player0 in [Displaying Lakhs and Crores in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69959242/13045193). Note that this workaround gives text strings that look like currency values rather than real numeric currency values.

Comment: Thanks. Got it that this is impossible to work on. 

What needs to be done so that inplace of 0 I can give - symbol?

Comment: I do not think I understand your new question. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead. See [Date & number formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats).